# xcode component to compare textual contents?

Tags: xcode, macos, file, diff

I'm wondering, is there a free (preferrably free software) component I can embed in an xcode application that when I select from two file tree views a file, it will compare them against of each other.

I'm thinking that this has been done 1000 times before, so instead of building my own, I'm looking to import a component which can when given two files, show them compared against each other in the way that eclipse does, or that meld does.

thanks

Comment: Are you writing an application for Mac OS? You may want to tag appropriately if so.